# Set node version for a single command using nvm

Tags: node.js, shell, nvm

I have a command that *must* be run with Node 16 installed, no other version. However, I need to have the latest version of Node installed for regular use.

How can I configure things, perhaps with environment variables, so that just that one command uses Node 16?

Something like `nvm use 16 && node -v && nvm use 19` is too slow, but aliasing in `.zshrc` is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in one of my Projects is this:

I've switched to node 16: `nvm use 16`.
After that `which node` showed this path: `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node`

So I've simply created a symlink for this executable: `ln -s $(which node) /usr/bin/node16`

Finally I switched back the version: `nvm use system`

Now you can use your default node Version with `node` and the desired node-version for this command with `node16`.

Comment: That works for other purposes, but not for mine. As I mentioned in my question, I am not running a script using `node`, but I am running a command which calls `node` directly and out of my control.

Comment: Well then.. First thing, my brain jumped to, was this: rearranging the `/usr/bin/node` by symlinks just before you call the script and later revert the change.
That's extremely dirty but should be faster than `nvm use`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with this: `ln -s $(which node16) $HOME/bin/node && node -v && unlink $(which node)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answer your question. But I have too similar requirements where a Go program triggers a Node.js program using Golang `os/exec` package. That Node.js program must run on a specific version of node (in my case **14.17.0**) and I was using `nvm` which has **17.5.0** set in my system.

So, I was able to switch version dynamically from 17.5.0 to 14.17.0 using environment variable set before running Go program.

```
export NVM_BIN=/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin
export PATH=$NVM_BIN:$PATH

# `echo $PATH` output should contains this path at the beginning for node i.e. /Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin
```